# sent_tokenize not working properly

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I am new to NlTK and I used function `sent_tokenize` on two strings which is giving different output than expected

**1) First string**

```
sent_tokenize("An uncle is the female sibbling of one's parents. An aunt can also be the wife of an [[uncle]] who is the male sibbling of a parent")
```

output:

> ["An uncle is the female sibbling of one's parents.",
>    'An aunt can also be the wife of an [[uncle]] who is the male sibbling of a parent']

**2) Second sting**

```
sent_tokenize("An uncle is the female [[sibbling]] of one's [[parent]]s. An aunt can also be the wife of an [[uncle]] who is the male sibbling of a parent")
```

output:

> ["An uncle is the female [[sibbling]] of one's [[parent]]s. An aunt can also be the wife of an [[uncle]] who is the male sibbling of a parent"]

here in second it's not giving two sentences as in first what might be the issue?

(we can use split and delimiter as "." and get the sentences but want to know what is the problem here)

Answer (score 1):

**The sent_tokenize function uses  punkt tokenizer that only works on well formed English.**

A full stop might not always mean the end of a sentence. For instance: "e.g. or i.e" .

**Make sure your sentences are well formed in English before tokenizing them.**

In your case, a simple space after 's' or replacing [[parent]]s by parents resolves the issue, but if this doesn't match your requirements, make sure to figure out a way to clean your text first.

You can read more about Punkt tokenizer [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py), this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your sentences, but I guess you can write second sentence as below, it works fine:

```
sentence2 = "An uncle is the female [[sibbling]] of one's [[parent]]s . An aunt can also be the wife of an [[uncle]] who is the male sibbling of a parent"
```

But if you write words in sentence without square brackets then also it works fine. I don't know why you are specifying words square brackets.

In my gitHub(https://github.com/rameshjesswani/Semantic-Textual-Similarity/blob/master/nlp_basics/nltk/text_normalization.ipynb), I already worked on basic text processing using NLTK, you can look on it.